# Unable to use Protractor webdriver-manager

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am trying to start protractor on my local Windows development machine. In an attempt to do so, I am trying to start it from the command-line using the following command:

```
C:\myProject\node_modules\grunt-protractor-runner\node_modules\protractor\bin>webdriver-manager start
```

When that command is run, I get an error that says:

```
'webdriver-manager' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I was confident this was correct though. I'm installing protractor via NPM. My package.json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Just the description",
  "repository": "N/A",
  "readme":"N/A",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.1.3",   
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "0.5.x",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "0.2.4",
    "grunt-start-webdriver":"0.0.2",
    "phantomjs": "1.9.7-3",
    "selenium-webdriver":"2.41.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "0.2.x",
  },
  "license": "none"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I get protractor to run? Thank you!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

webdriver-manager is actually a NodeJS script. Run it using

```
node webdriver-manager start
```

Comment: If you install protractor properly, `webdriver-manager`is a runnable command. See [Rassel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378410/2197555)

Answer (score 36):

Install protractor globally.

```
npm install protractor -g
```

This will install `protractor` and `webdriver-manager`.
Then run from the command line: `webdriver-manager update`
Check for more info on: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/tutorial

Answer (score 15):

Try installing it globally as an Administrator:

```
npm install -g webdriver-manager
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are a Windows user, this could help you:

1. Add `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\npm` to the `PATH` variable.
2. Close cmd/powershell and open it again.
3. Try `webdriver-manager`

Answer (score 2):

use [grunt-protractor-webdriver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-webdriver), you also need `protractor` in your package.json if you don`t installed it as global (`-g`)

add this to your `package.json` under `"devDependencies":`

```
    "protractor": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.2.0",
```

also look at [grunt-protractor-runner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner) it can start protractor from a grunt process without starting the selenium server ( `webdriver-manager start` )

to start the selenium server with `grunt-protractor-webdriver` add this to your Gruntfile

```
    protractor_webdriver: {
        options: {
          keepAlive: true
        }
    }
```

and add it to a grunt-task

```
    grunt.registerTask('start-selenium-server', ['protractor_webdriver']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated version of node - it was problem on my pc.

Just updated it downloading last version from https://nodejs.org/en/ and all works.