# Protactor error, Unexpected token )

Tags: node.js, protractor

I was about start learning protractor and following the simple tutorial in there http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

but unfortunately getting weird error after run this command `protractor conf.js`

```
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1
   /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:126
       throw e;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
  at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
  at Object.goog.loadModule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1:6
  at Object.Context.closure.goog.retrieveAndExecModule_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:135:8)
  at <anonymous>:1:6
  at Context.closure.closure.vm.createContext.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/_base.js:104:12)
  at Object.goog.importScript_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:879:9)
  at Object.goog.importModule_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:900:14)
  at Object.goog.writeScripts_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1323:16)
  at Object.goog.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:663:14)
```

node version : v0.10.37

java version : 1.8.0_66

protractor   : Version 3.0.0

jadmine : jasmine v2.3.2 jasmine-core v2.3.4

UPDATE

already clone the repository https://github.com/angular/protractor

run following command

`./bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone`

`./bin/webdriver-manager start`

open new terminal tab

change to website direcotry

run the website folder using `npm start` and the website already running on port 8080

open new terminal tab, still under website folder

run test command `npm test` then chrome browser open up in a few second
and show same error above

Comment: Have you tried to run `node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update`?

Comment: yes, i was try run that before `selenium standalone is up to date.` `chromedriver is up to date`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Protractor upgraded to WebDriver `2.48.2` with their release of version `3.0.0`. This version of WebDriver is not compatible with Node.js versions < `4`.

From `CHANGELOG.md` in the Protractor project:

> (18e1f71) chore(webdriver): upgrade Protractor to webdriver 2.48.2
>
> BREAKING CHANGE:
>       **1) Users will no longer be able to use node versions < 4.**
>     2) There are significant changes to the control flow, and tests may need to be modified to be compliant with the new control flow. See [Changes](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md)

Downgrading Protractor to `2.5.1` or upgrading Node.js to >= v`4.0.0` should solve your problem. See [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/148f020bf4bbd71e17326581a2f7ed6f4ff55832/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) for more info on breaking changes in Protractor v3.0.0.

Comment: Protractor should post this message in the tutorial itself. Two people in my office had the same problem, without this foot-note in the change log we would be stuck.

Comment: I have v5.12.0 but still same.

Comment: `npm install protractor -g`. This will install protractor and webdriver-manager. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23580315/unable-to-use-protractor-webdriver-manager