# How to run protractor testcases in Jenkins with a headless browser?

Tags: jenkins, protractor, headless-browser

I have used phantomjs but compatibility of phantom js is bad with protractor. Though in chrome and firefox browser I am able to find elements but same locators are not found in phantomjs.

Comment: You need to narrow your question down. Is Jenkins on Linux? Do you have access to a Windows slave that can run the tests for you? Does the Jenkins box have a GUI part? Jenkins will run Chrome just fine, if it is installed on that system.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using linux OS then you can use `xvfb` to launch the chrome browser in headless mode.

To install xvfb, run the below commands in terminal

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
```

Once you install xfvb, you can run your protractor scripts using the below command,

```
xvfb-run protractor configuration.js
```

The above command will start your chrome browser in headless mode and will execute all specs mentioned in the configuration.js file.

Comment: Thank you Sudharasan ffor your quick reply.  Now I am facing below issue: [launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-automationtest-master/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-automationtest-

Comment: My Package.Json:-

Comment: are you facing the same issue when you run protractor without xvfb-rub?

Comment: No It works fine when I run without xvfb-run in my local.  But When I am trying to run with xvfb in Jenkin, I am getting above error.

Comment: Which os are you using and have you tried running the xvfb-run in terminal directly?

Comment: Below i have added my conf.js , package json, scripts which i am using to run protractor from Jenkin and error which i am getting from Jenkin. Please have a look and help

Comment: I am using Ubuntu. I am getting an error as 'xvfb-run error xvfb failed to start' . i have added a new script.sh file. plz have a look and help.

Answer (score 1):

### My Package.JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Protractor-Test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "UI Automation of Media WorkFlow by Protractor",
  "main": "conf.js",
  "author": "Subhasish Mishra",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "jasmine-expect": "~2.0.1",
    "jasmine-reporters": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~3.1.1",
    "protractor-console": "~2.0.1",
    "protractor-html-screenshot-reporter": "0.0.21",
    "protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.6",
    "selenium-webdriver": "~2.53.2",
    "webdriver-manager":"10.2.1"
  }
}
```

[image: My conf.js file]

My `script.sh` to trigger protractor test from Jenkins

New `script.sh` file
[image]

Error after build from Jenkins

```
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-automationtest-master/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/q/q.js:155
                throw e;
                      ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
    at goog.loadModuleFromSource_ (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-automationtest-master/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1123:19)
    at Object.goog.loadModule (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-automationtest-master/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/base.js:1085:46)
    at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/media-msod-a
```

Comment: which version of nodejs are you using in your jenkins server machine? please look at this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33818869/protactor-error-unexpected-token