# WebDriverError error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: linux, google-chrome, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, xvfb

I'm trying to run protractor test on ubuntu 14.04 vm (by google cloud),
for some reason when i run 'protractor conf.js' i get an error says:

**E/launcher - WebDriverError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally**

I followed this tasks in order to install headless chrome:
https://gist.github.com/alonisser/11192482

- Before running protractor cons.js, i'm running *"webdriver-manager start"*
- When i run 'Xvfb -ac :2 -screen 0 1280x1024x16' its freeze when gets to
  'Initializing built-in extension GLX'
- I also tried change the conf.js to
  chromeOptions: {
     args: [ "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=800x600" ]'
  but and protractor print 'start' then error: 'Failed: unknown error: an X display is required for keycode conversions, consider using Xvfb'
- It's important to mention that it's all worked great, before a couple hours.
  then i just let my mac sleep, and of course it was exit the vm..
- I'm running the same tests with protractor in my mac and its works great.
  **the problem is related to chrome/chromeDriver on the instance vm.**

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Can you also tell us the versions of Chrome and Chromedriver which you are using. Chrome has just been updated to version 59 so you need to have ChromeDriver 2.30

Comment: google-chrome --version -> `Google Chrome 59.0.3071.104` chromedriver --version -> `ChromeDriver 2.30.477691`

also: `webdriver-manager@12.0.6` and `protractor@5.1.2`

Comment: Hope this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39080917/how-to-run-protractor-testcases-in-jenkin-with-a-headless-browser

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem when using selenium + python 2.7 + chromedriver in a AWS EC2 machine.

In my case I was using the newest headless feature, so adding '**no-sandbox**' parameter to the ChromeOptions object did the trick.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

The problem seems to be a permission issue with chrome. It does not allow a 'root' user to execute it without the --no-sandbox flag

Comment: `no-sandbox` is exactly what fixed my issue in an Ubuntu Server 16.04 machine on Azure. thank you!

Comment: It works for me. For later versions, arg chrome_options is deprecated and replaced by options.

Comment: Also, in my case I don't need no-sandbox option. It seems to be safer not using that if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out, the answer is in my question.

You should run the command **`Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16`**

and right after **`export DISPLAY=:99`**

I also add to my start.sh script the command **`export DISPLAY=:99`**
The order seems to be important. You can ignore the error of the GLX when running the Xvfb, it can work without it.